# Push different view with no tab bar in UINavigation [like Photos app]

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITabbarController with UItableViewController for each tabs, when I navigate down in a tableview Tab bar still there, but I want to make detail view with no tab bar (just like photos app when you click on a photo tab bar disappear and replace with tool bar). How can I implement this kind of behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` where self is your `DetailViewController`? Try it before pushing the `DetailViewController`.